# Redux reducer state returns NaN value when component is mounted, but works fine when is updated

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I wanted to create a simple counter by redux (I don't use dispatch method)

This is my `Action` code:

```
export const increaseNumber = () => {
    return {type: 'INCREASE'}
}
export const decreaseNumber = () => {
    return {type: 'DEACREASE'}
}
export const clearNumber = () => {
    return {type: 'CLEARNUMBER'}
}
```

This is my `Reducer` file:

```
initialState = {
    number: 3
}

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'INCREASE':
            return { number: state.number + 2 }
            break;
        case 'DEACREASE':
            return { number: state.number - 5 }
            break;
        case 'CLEARNUMBER':
            return { number: 0 }
            break;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

And this is my `mapStateToProps` code:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {number: state.counterR.number}
}
```

Then i put state like this into component:

```
<Text>{props.number}</Text>
```

This is the rootReducer that i've named `index.js` into reducers folder :

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import counterReducer from './counterRecducer';
import inputReducer from './inputRecucer';
import reducer from './reducer';


export default combineReducers({
   counterR: counterReducer,
   inputR: inputReducer,
   dialogR: reducer
})
```

This is `App.js` file:

```
import {CounterComponent} from './src/components';
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import reducers from './src/reducers';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={createStore(reducers)}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        < CounterComponent />
      </View>
    </Provider>
  )}
```

When i render component for the first time it returns NaN but when click on clear button It shows 0 and then increase and decrease button would work

How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: action code is do wrong actually

Comment: Which part is wrong?

Comment: if possible could you share the value of ```props.number```

Comment: @SDushan I already shared, Please take a look to above codes (reducer part) its value is initialState that has been defined 3

Comment: @roz333, would you like to share the rootReducer file?

Comment: Mind sharing where you call `createStore`? Also, what do you mean you're not using `dispatch`? How are you triggering your actions then? :o

Comment: @SuccessFollower I edited my question and added rootReducer Please check again above codes

Comment: @LonelyPrincess I called ```createStore``` into ```App.js``` i edited my question and added content of ```App.js``` please check again above codes.

Comment: Please share as much of your component code too.

Comment: did you write `export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CounterComponent)?

Comment: @SuccessFollower yes i did

Comment: would you like to share your repository?

Comment: @SuccessFollower Issue is solved buddy, Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When i render component for the first time it returns NaN but when
>   click on clear button It shows 0

So, it is not a problem related to the reducers, but to the initial state values.

**Solution**: when you create the store you should pass the `initialState` var as the second param, like this:

```
createStore(reducers, initialState)
```

So your `App` component will be like this:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={createStore(reducers, initialState)}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        < CounterComponent />
      </View>
    </Provider>
  )}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This error just happens when i use ```combineReducers``` but when i declare all actions in a single reducer everything work smoothly and i don't get above errors, Regarding to your solution, i tried but i got another error, error says ```user``` (```initialState``` in another reducer) passed to ```createStore```, How can i pass a particular ```initialState``` to ```createStore```

Comment: The initialState you use in the createStore must have the same shape that the reducers object that is the first param (the result of your combineReducers function). In your code it is an object with the keys `counterR`, `inputR` and `dialogR`. So you have to write something like this: 
```
const initialState = {
   counterR: { number: 3 },
   inputR: {},
   dialogR: {}
}
```
I don't know how to fill the `inputR` and `dialogR` values. Just follow than same criteria than counterR

Comment: You really genius buddy, It worked, Thank you so much.